# It is things VS it is a thing

Tags: cleft-constructions

Please check both sentences and let me know, which one is correct. As per my opinion it is(is) for singular thing so it should be it is the worst **thing** not it is the worst **things**.

**I read it somewhere**:

> **It is the worst things** that can bring out the best in you.

**As per my opinion:**

> **It is the worst thing** that can bring out the best in you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence. Your sentences are *it*-clefts. (Given the two sentences, I prefer the first one. You can even drop the *can*, "It is the worst things that bring out the best in you.") For more examples, try searching for "[it is they who are](https://www.google.com/search?q="it+is+they+who+are"&tbm=bks)".

Comment: @DamkerngT. Your comment has more votes than either answer. I think you should consider fleshing out your response to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original sentence is an example of a cleft sentence. We use **[cleft sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence)** structure to emphasize a particular part of the sentence by introducing that part first. Cleft sentences are very useful in writing because we couldn't raise our voice to stress particular words in our writing. What we can do is to rearrange the words to achieve a similar effect.

Consider:

> The worst things can bring out the best in you.

In speech, you can emphasize the word "worst", like this:

> The WORST things can bring out the best in you.

<sup>(Also note that we normally don't write in all caps because it will have the effect of raising your voice or shouting.)</sup>

However, in writing, you can do this:

> It is the worst things that can bring out the best in you.

With *it*-cleft sentence structure, it's now clear that you want to emphasize "the worst things". And the reason that you mentioned it is because it "can bring out the best in you."

There are several types of [cleft sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence) (see the linked Wikipedia page), Your original sentence is an ***it*-cleft**. Using *it*-clefts, you don't need to change *"It is ..."* to *"They are ..."* even when the emphasized part is a plural noun. (For example, see "[it is they who are](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it+is+they+who+are%22&tbm=bks)") One way to make sense of it is to think of this *it* in *"It is ..."* as **preparatory *it***. Also note that the main verb of the *that*-clause must agree with the emphasized noun. For example, *"It is you who are in the wrong."*

As a side note on "the worst things" versus "the worst thing", I would say that "the worst thing" is possible (in some context). However, "the worst things" is the better choice, generally speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Read it this way:

> It is **the worst things** that can bring out the best in you.

I think the phrase `"the worst things"` is used here as a single entity. Because if they say that `"it is the worst thing that brings out the best in you"`, it'll create a restriction and would mean that only one particular worst thing can bring the best out of you.

The author wants to say that the worst things make you stronger, but since it's used as a single entity, it has taken `"It is"`.

`"They are the worst things that can bring out the best in you`" probably did not look as easy as `"It is"` to the author.

However, many may argue that that's informal way of telling the sentence.

Comment: I've edited your answer to remove the square brackets that made me think that portion of the text was optional and could be removed from the sentence.

Comment: and regarding the discussion whether to use "it is" or "they are", I think @DamkerngT. got it right in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's take these one at a time, because they're both correct to say (killed the big spoiler at the beginning, but that's no problem)

> It is the worst things that can bring out the best in you.

'The worst things' is a general term meaning, well, all the worst things. It doesn't point at anything in particular. It is simply a general term. An example of its usage would be describing, say, Pandora's Box: 'it contains all the worst things in the world'. Because it is a phrase in itself, it's referred to as one object, hence the 'is' instead of 'are', which is used for multiple things normally.

The second sentence:

> It is the worst thing that can bring out the best in you.

This is correct but has a different meaning. When you talk about one 'thing' you are specifically talking about something. When you say 'the worst thing in the world' it implies that you can *name that thing*.

What you read is likely to be making a general reference to bad things, which is when you would use the first sentence, because it talks in a general way. The second sentence is for when you were talking about one thing specifically.

Might I also add, that this the question about English that has thrown me the most so far on this site, and I thank you for asking it.